# setting ABUnknownPersonViewController's person's image leaks, how do i fix this?

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

```
ABRecordRef thecomicstrip = NULL;
person = ABPersonCreate();

//LEAKS
UIImage *iconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_icon.png"];
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(iconImage);
ABPersonSetImageData(thecomicstrip, (CFDataRef)data, nil);

ABUnknownPersonViewController * unknownPersonViewController = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
unknownPersonViewController.allowsAddingToAddressBook = NO;
unknownPersonViewController.displayedPerson = person;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:unknownPersonViewController animated:NO];
[unknownPersonViewController release];

CFRelease(person);
```

I need to set the image without it leaking. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on 4.2? ABPersonSetImageData seems to be leaking on it. Try the code on earlier iOS.

Comment: I am on 4.2. I only have 4.2 sdk installed, how do you install older versions?

Comment: You don't need to downgrade the SDK, just the iOS running on your device or simulator (Easiest: Hardware | Versions).